# zf3 skeleton application not working when change module.config.php of Application module

Tags: zend-framework3

zf3 not work well when change route of Appliation module

download a zf3 skeleton application ,change route of zf3

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'application' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/application[/:action]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

I change it to :

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/test',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'application' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/testapplication[/:action]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

when i visit /test and /testapplication/index , i got 404 page not found error, it seems zf3 can't route to this path

Comment: Can you tell us how the full path (full url) is looking like? Do you run ZF3 skeleton on localhost or do you installed it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the skeleton app and run it without touching anything, then the problem is the cache.

If you look in the application config file (`config/application.config.php`), you will find these lines:

```php
return [
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // Line 33
        'config_cache_enabled' => true
    ]
];
```

This will create a cache file under the cache directory (by default, `data/cache`, as defined in `application.config.php` at line 47).

For development purposes, I suggest you to disable the cache. The best way to do that is to remove the `.dist` from the `config/development.config.php.dist` configuration file.

Comment: it really works when i disable the cache, thank you very much