# Zend framework 3 tutorial error 404 after setting database : The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm trying Zend framework 3 for a project and I followed the tutorial. The 404 errors occurs after setting the route and controller, exactly at the end of this part : https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/routing-and-controllers/

The error :

> A 404 error occurred Page not found.
>
> The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller
>   class.
>
> Controller:    Controller\AlbumController (resolves to invalid
>   controller class or alias: Controller\AlbumController)
>
> No Exception available

I tried some Zend 2 fix but It make it worse.

This is my Album\config\module.config.php

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Did I missed something? Is it broken? 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Did you disabled the cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zf3 skeleton application not working when change module.config.php of Application module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857834/zf3-skeleton-application-not-working-when-change-module-config-php-of-applicatio)

Comment: I will try @Ermenegildo

Comment: Ok, i remove the ".dist" from development.config.php but it didn't change anything ~@Ermenegildo

Comment: In the configuration you posted, there is no declaration of the controller (lines 7-11 of the first snippet in the tutorial page). Did you forgot it or you just omitted it here?

Comment: They tell us to remove it "Because we're now defining our own factory, we can modify our module.config.php to remove the definition. Open module/Album/config/module.config.php and remove the following lines" [link]https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#back-to-the-controller @Ermenegildo

Comment: Of course, but you still have to declare it. In the configuration you provided, there is no controller declaration. Did you added in the `Module` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Ermenegildo I figured it out. The problem was located is Module.php where some dependencies were missing.

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
```