# zend framework 3 segment routing doesn't work

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework3

I have the following module.config.php :

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'landingpage' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/landingpage[/:action/:id]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\LandingPageController::class,
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ]
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\LandingPageController::class => LandingPageControllerFactory::class
        ]
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'LandingPage\Service\LandingPageService' => 'LandingPage\Service\LandingPageService'
        ]
    ]
];
```

I am trying to use the following route and it doesn't work:

> http://localhost:8081/landingpage/show/1CGe2cveQ

If I use the following route it works :

> http://localhost:8081/landingpage/show

If I use the previous route with a / it doesn't work:

> http://localhost:8081/landingpage/show/

If you need more info let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double slash in the route declaration: the route is matched by `/landingpage/` followed by `/:action/:id`. If you remove this double slash, the route will work as expected.

```php
'route' => '/landingpage[/:action/:id]',
```

Moreover, I'd suggest you to modify the route declaration to make the id optional:

```php
'route' => '/landingpage[/:action[/:id]]',
'constraints' => [
    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
    'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
]
```

Tested:
**config**

```php
'landingpage' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/landingpage[/:action[/:id]]',
        'constraints' => [
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
            'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
],
```

**IndexController:**

```php
public function indexAction () {
    print '<pre>' . print_r($this->params()->fromRoute(), true);
    die(); 
}
public function showAction(){
    print '<pre>' . print_r($this->params()->fromRoute(), true);
    die();
}
```

Calling **/landingpage**

```php
Array
(
    [controller] => Application\Controller\IndexController
    [action] => index
)
```

Calling **/landingpage/show**

```php
Array
(
    [controller] => Application\Controller\IndexController
    [action] => show
)
```

Calling **/landingpage/show/1CGe2cveQ**

```php
Array
(
    [controller] => Application\Controller\IndexController
    [action] => show
    [id] => 1CGe2cveQ
)
```

Don't forget to clear the configuration cache, if it enabled ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but didn't solve the problem! I already tried like you said and didn't work.

Comment: The route is correct and works fine, as you can see from the results. If your code isn't still working, then the problem is somewhere else. Did you cleared the cache? What's the error message? Could you paste your _merged_ configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I'll update the post as soon as I try what you said. How can i clear the configuration cache?

Comment: Best solution is to disable configuration cache (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864921/1842846)), or you can just remove all files in folder `data/cache`